# Need to select a checkbox in WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I need to tick the Add GPUs check box. WebSite https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator
There is a code

```
WebElement checkAddGRU = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.
                    presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//md-input-container/md-checkbox/div[contains(text(),'Add GPUs')]")));
    WebElement numberOfGPU = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//md-select[@placeholder='Number of GPUs']")));
    while (!numberOfGPU.isDisplayed()) {
        checkAddGRU.click();
    }
```

But it don't work. The checkbox leasted empty.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not able to select the checkbox is due to the presence of the checkbox in an iframe. Try switching to iframe first and then select the checkbox.

```
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#myFrame"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//md-input-container/md-checkbox/div[contains(text(),'Add GPUs')]").click()
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, did not indicate. I switched to the frame previously in this way. driver.switchTo().frame(0);
driver.switchTo().frame("myFrame");